# Solving this ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having a struggle solving this equation. y1 is one of the bases for solutions.

$$x\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-(1+x)\frac{dy}{dx}+y=0$$
$$y_1=1+x$$
Can anyone show me how to solve this equation by steps?
Thank you.

Comment: By simple inspection , can you see that another solution is $y=e^x$?

Comment: No. I have no idea.

Answer (score 3):

you already have one solution. you need a second one to form a basis of the space of solutions since it's a second order ODE. 
you can proceed in different ways. one approach is the method of variation of parameters.

suppose the 2nd solution is of the form $j(x)y_1(x)$. and plug that in into the ode.

after that you'll get :

$$x(x+1)j''(x)-(x^2+1)j'(x) = 0$$

can you take it from here ?

also after you're done with the computation you could compute the [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian) to make sure they're independent.

Comment: I have reached that point already, but couldn't go far from there.

Comment: @galoiasuteva I see. integration is a pain in the neck.

Answer (score 2):

By visual inspection one can come to the factorization
$$
\left(x\frac{d}{dx}-1\right)\left(\frac{d}{dx}-1\right)y=0
$$
or in separate steps
$$
y'-y=v\\
xv'-v=0
$$
where the second can be easily integrated to $\frac{v}x=C$, while the first has the general solution form $y=Ae^x+Bx+D$ with coefficient conditions $-B=C$, $B-D=0$ so that
$$
y=Ae^x+B(1+x).
$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to solve the equation using this method.

Answer (score 1):

$$x\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-(1+x)\frac{dy}{dx}+y=0$$
$$xy''-y'-xy'+y=0$$
$$x(y''-y')-(y'-y)=0$$
Substitute $z=y'-y$
$$xz'-z=0$$
Which is a first order differential equation easy to solve
$$\int \frac {dz}{z}=\int \frac {dx} x=\ln|x|+K \implies z=Kx$$
$$y'-y=Kx$$
Take $e^{-x}$ as an integrating factor...
$$(ye^{-x})'=Kxe^{-x}$$
Just integrate..
$$\boxed{y=Ke^{x}\int xe^{-x} dx}$$
$$.....$$

Comment: I like this way of solving the equation. Thank you!